# Laravel and mySQL with relational tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to create an API with laravel and PHP.
I've created api routes to `GET` all users and `GET` all devices related to the user.

I've made the following tables in mySQL:

**Devices:**

```
increments('id');
string('name');
longText('description');
```

**Table for relations between users and devices:**

```
increments('id');
unsignedInteger('user_id');
unsignedInteger('device_id');

foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
foreign('device_id')->references('id')->on('devices');
```

**Variables:**

```
increments('id');
string('type');
unsignedInteger('device_id');
longText('description');

foreign('device_id')->references('id')->on('devices');
```

And the models have the relationscode:

**User Model:**

```
public function deviceVariables() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\DeviceVariable');
}

public function devices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Device');
}
```

**Device Model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

public function variables()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\DeviceVariable');
}
```

And finally the **DeviceVariable Model:**

```
public function device()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Device');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I am able to show all the devices related to an authenticated user, but i am unable to show all the variables related to the devices that are related to that user.

This code (index method of `DeviceVariablecontroller`) is the closest i've come to getting the variables:

```
$counter = 1;
$arrayIndex = 0;
while($counter <= 10) {
    if(auth()->user()->devices()->find($counter)) {
        $variables[$arrayIndex] = auth()->user()->devices()->find($counter)->variables;
        $arrayIndex++;
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Is there a way to make an array of all the user's devices' IDs and the loop through them?- or is there a smarter way to get all the variables of all the user's devices?

**EDIT:**
Comment got me both the devices aswell as the each device variables.

```
$variables = auth()->user()->devices()->with('variables')->get();
return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'data' => $variables
]);
```

How can i get the variables ONLY without the device info?

Comment: What you get in `$variables`?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `$variables = auth()->user()->devices()->with('variables')->get();`

Comment: @SandOfVega I get an object to all the variables related to the device with ID = 1. But the new edit gives all the variable objects related to all devices (as long as the user doesn't have more than 10 devices)

Comment: @LukášIrsák got me what i wanted! But i also get the devices returned aswell. How can i do so that only the variables are returned?

Comment: "How can i get the variables ONLY without the device info?" You can't. Since the variables directly depends on the device and not the user, you can't get them directly from an user. You need to get the device in order to get the variables.

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: i see.. well i'm going to read a bit more on the documentation, but for now i'll go with @LukášIrsák.

Comment: My laravel version is the latest 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$variables = auth()->user()->devices()->with('variables')->get();
```

This will eager load relationships that devices had.

For accessing only users variables you can use has-many-throught relationship like mentioned in docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: The problem is that the device doesn't have any field 'user_id' as these relations are made through a third table ("Table for relations between users and devices" in the post) Is the documented has-many-through relationship possible with my setup? Or should i remove the third table and just add 'user_id' column in the 'device' table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BelongsToMany` relationship to get the variables directly:

```
public function variables()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\DeviceVariable', 'device_user',
        null, 'device_id', null, 'device_id');
}

return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'data' => auth()->user()->variables
]);
```

Comment: Well the thing is, the variables don't belong directly to a user but only to a specific device. So variables don't belong to many users, they belong to a single device which further belongs to many users.

Comment: Yes, but we can use a trick to "skip" the `devices` table by joining `device_user.device_id = variables.device_id` directly. Did you try it?